# Method String[,]

Tags: c#, methods

Here is my main method I call my Boolean method.

```cs
DataTable dt = (ds.Tables[0].DefaultView).ToTable();
DataColumn col = dt.Columns["SliderSN"];
sliderMethod(col);
```

Here is my other method:

```cs
private bool sliderMethod(string[,] SliderSN)
{
    string strErr = null;
    try
    {
        int slider = 0;
        slider_data[] SliderBinData = new slider_data[SliderSN.GetLength(0)];
        for (int y = 0; y < SliderSN.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            if (SliderSN[y, 0] != null && SliderSN[y, 1] != null && SliderSN[y, 1].Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                SliderBinData[slider] = new slider_data();
                SliderBinData[slider].SliderSN = SliderSN[y, 1];
                SliderBinData[slider].ParmName = "ISBLTSAMPLE";
                SliderBinData[slider].ParmValue = "1";
                slider++;
            }
        }

        if (slider > 0)
        {
            WebService.Slider2(SliderBinData);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            strErr = "Nothing to Update";
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        strErr = ex.ToString();
        return false;
    }
}
```

My problem is I don't know what parameter I put in my main method for `sliderMethod();` after my DataColumn.

Comment: What kind of data you are expecting in `string[,] SliderSN` ?

Comment: Have you considered using an array of `(string, string)` [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples) instead of `string[,]`?

Comment: Hi iMemew, did one of the solutions below help you out, you can type in the comment box if you need further help

Comment: Please don't add solved or closed to the title. Instead mark the answer which solved the problem, as answer or if you solve it yourself, post your answer.

Comment: In addition to what @Reza has said, don't include tags in the title, don't include irrelevant tags (i.e. only include tags that are actually what the question is _about_), and please leave out conversational text. These flaws have been addressed by their edit and mine, but please keep these guidelines in mind in the future. Also, make sure you take the tour, and read [ask] and [mcve] especially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private bool sliderMethod(string[,] SliderSN)
```

The `sliderMethod` takes in a [2 dimensional string array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays). Normally a table with x and y axis would create a two dimensional array but what you are trying to pass is a single column.

Convert your table to Multi-Dimensional array and then send that to the method.

```
DataTable dt = (ds.Tables[0].DefaultView).ToTable();

// Using 1 for Columns since you are working with one column only, "SliderSN"
int rowCount = dt.Rows.Count;
object[,] arr = new object[rowCount, 1]; 

int i = 0;
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
  arr[i++, 0] = row["SliderSN"].ToString();

slider(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you sir this solve my problem i am grateful to you. Thank you very much sir @Jawad.

Comment: You should consider accepting any answer that solved your problem by clicking the check-mark.